# how to export fusionchart in PHP

Tags: php, fusioncharts

I want to export **fusionchart** to images or pdf , what should I add? without using a third party

```
<?php

*//koneksi database*
include "config/koneksi.php";
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE | E_DEPRECATED));
include "config/koneksi.php";
include("config/class/FusionCharts_Gen.php");
$pencarian=$_POST['pencarian'];
$bulan=$_POST['bulan'];
$barang_aset=$_POST['barang_aset'];


?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>First Chart Using FusionCharts PHP Class</title>
    <script language='javascript' src='assets/js/FusionCharts.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <?php
```

> # Include FusionCharts PHP Class
>         # Create object for Column 3D chart

```
  $FC = new FusionCharts("column3d","900","450");

  # Setting Relative Path of chart swf file.
  $FC->setSwfPath("Charts/");

  # Store chart attributes in a variable
  $strParam="caption=Grafik Jumlah Inventaris dan Aset Berdasarkan Kategori";

  # Set chart attributes
  $FC->setChartParams($strParam);

  $kategori = mysql_query("SELECT id_kategori, nama_kategori FROM kategori");
  //$tracking = mysql_query("SELECT Nama_Karyawan FROM master_karyawan WHERE Kode_Nama_Cabang='SRJ' AND Category_Tracking='sales'");
while ($r_kat = mysql_fetch_array($kategori)){

    $id_kat = $r_kat['id_kategori'];
    $kat = $r_kat['nama_kategori'];

    $counter1 = 0;`enter code here`

**What do I need to add to add exportEnabled in this fusionchart**

             //$total = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT IdKat,TglTerjual FROM penjualan_buku WHERE IdKat='$kat' AND LEFT(TglTerjual,4)='2012' AND  MID(TglTerjual,6,2)='02'"));

             $total = mysql_query("SELECT id_kategori, nama_barang FROM barang WHERE id_kategori='$id_kat' and nama_barang like '%$_POST[barang_aset]%'and MONTH(tanggal_status) like '%$_POST[bulan]%' and status like '%$_POST[pencarian]%' ");

             $counter1++;


    //$persentase = ($total!=0 || $review !=0)?($review / $total) *100:0;
    $total = mysql_num_rows($total);


  # add chart values and category names
  $FC->addChartData("$total","name=<a href='jmlaset.php?id=$id_kat'>$kat</a>");

}
    # Render Chart
    $FC->renderChart();
  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

How do I add an export function in this **fusionchart**?

Comment: sorry sloppy code , please can be viewed here http://pastebin.com/s4P7aRDA

Answer (score 0):

Your php wrapper class for FusionCharts is not validating with the latest wrapper class please see the [link](http://www.fusioncharts.com/php-charts/)

you can also export chart through FusionCharts export server by setting the attribute `exportEnabled` to `1`. This will use their export server and will download the image at your end.

If you want to create your own export server, you can use the FusionCharts' distributable export handler. You can get useful information from this [link](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/usage-guide/interactivity/exporting-as-image-and-pdf/setup-private-export-server-php.html) but it uses two third party api ImageMagick and InkScape to convert SVG to required image formats. You need to install this dependencies at your end.